# part number of switching regulator component

Tags: identification, components, switching-regulator

Can somebody help me to read this component part number?
i think its switching regulator.
thank you.[image: ic]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the 2A comes back to a MMBT3906 There are a few different variations and some of the manufacturers put a smaller letter on for date as well. [MMBT3906-TP](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/micro-commercial-co/MMBT3906-TP/MMBT3906-TPCT-ND/819686) is one from MCC. Comes back as a transistor though and not a regulator.
Desc: TRANS PNP 40V 0.2A SOT23

[image]

Comment: thank you robert.but im looking for that 6 pin component

Comment: Sorry about that. Only option I came accross was if the part is updise down and the H8 marking could be IMH8A or UMH8N from Rohm. Not sure though they don't show the part markings on the data sheet.